# Android. StaggeredGridLayoutManager gapStrategy makes View invisible

Tags: android, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I use a RecyclerView to show 2 column layout with some items as sections, using the full width. This is how I am setting up my RecyclerView:

```
fun bindRV() {
    val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
    layoutManager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
    recyclerViewServicesBlock.layoutManager = layoutManager
    serviceBlockAdapter.items = serviceViewModel.getServiceBlockItems()
    recyclerViewServicesBlock.adapter = serviceBlockAdapter
}
```

When I set gapStrategy to GAP_HANDLING_NONE items not showing.
For example, I expect in the left column: A, C, E, G, in the right column: B, D, F, H; but I have this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/138Zg.png).

I am trying to set gap strategy first then bind the adapter and vice versa

Comment: You may want to specify a question. Otherwise people might find it difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: @Krokomot where exactly to indicate what may not be clear

Comment: In the whole everything's fine. Sorry, I should have said it another way -- It's preferable to formulate an explicit question a la "How could ..." instead of just stating "I'm trying to ...". That will improve your chances for a proper answer.